# WSS_Content -- what localization?

Tags: database, sharepoint

Is there a way to get current SharePoint localization (or culture like "en-US"), querying DB WSS_Content?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use the SharePoint object model through powershell), to get the current locale for a site. Never use the sharepoint databases directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OM you can use [SPWeb.RegionalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473942.aspx) to get an [SPRegionalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spregionalsettings.aspx) object